# Unable to use between clause with date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my MySQL query.

```
SELECT Timestamp,a_number,Verdict,OrderId 
FROM Main 
WHERE Timestamp between DATE '2014-03-12' AND '2014-03-11' 
and a_location like '%london%';
```

In above query Timestamp is one of the field in Main table. But when i execute the query it is executing and getting the output as empty set.

When I checked Timestamp values that stored in database i am getting the values that are given below

1323517427743,1323867674980.

What is the mistake that i have done. And what should i make change to get my need.

Answer (score 2):

`col BETWEEN a AND b` is a syntactic sugar over `col >= a AND col <= n` - i.e., you must use the correct order:

```
SELECT Timestamp,a_number,Verdict,OrderId 
FROM   Main 
WHERE  Timestamp between DATE '2014-03-11' AND '2014-03-12' 
AND    a_location like '%london%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using back ticks around the DATE column

```
SELECT Timestamp,a_number,Verdict,OrderId 
FROM Main 
WHERE Timestamp between `DATE` '2014-03-12' AND '2014-03-11' 
and a_location like '%london%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `Timestamp`'s column type is `timestamp`, then you could just do:

```
SELECT `Timestamp`, a_number,Verdict,OrderId 
FROM Main 
WHERE `Timestamp` between '2014-03-11' AND '2014-03-12' 
and a_location like '%london%';
```

If it is integer, then you should do:

```
SELECT `Timestamp`, a_number,Verdict,OrderId 
FROM Main 
WHERE `Timestamp` between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-11') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-12') 
and a_location like '%london%';
```

And for `between A and B`, `A` should less or equal than `B`, or no result will be returned.

Comment: I have changed the command as you suggested, But still it resulting empty only.